# How should I pass classNames into a react component when using Webpack’s local scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using [Webpack’s local scope](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#local-scope) to create CSS classes that are scoped to the component they belong to.

I have an `<Icon />` React component that looks like this:

**Icon.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react')
var styles = require('./Icon.css')

module.exports = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        iconName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        height: React.PropTypes.number,
        width: React.PropTypes.number,
        classes: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            iconName: 'cloud',
            height: 36,
            width: 36,
            classes: ''
        };
    },

    render() {

        var iconSize = {
            height: this.props.height + 'px',
            width: this.props.width + 'px'
        }

        return (
            <i className={this.props.classes + ' ' + styles[this.props.iconName]} style={iconSize} />
        )
    }
})
```

… with CSS that looks like this:

**Icon.css**

```
.base {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.cloud {
    composes: base;
    background-image: url("./images/cloud.svg");
    transform: translate3d(0, -12px, 0);
}
.apps {
    composes: base;
    background-image: url("./images/apps.svg");
    transform: translate3d(0, -11px, 0);
}
```

I'm pulling it into another component called `<Capsule />` where I need to position it in a way that's specific to the `<Capsule />` component.

**Capsule.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react')
var styles = require('./Capsule.css')

var Icon = require('../Icon/Icon.jsx')

module.exports = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        clickable: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        iconName: React.PropTypes.string,
        label: React.PropTypes.string,
        cta: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            clickable: true,
            iconName: '',
            label: '',
            cta: ''
        };
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.withIcon}>
                {this.props.iconName ? <Icon classes={styles.icon} iconName={this.props.iconName} /> : ''}
                {this.props.label ? <span className={styles.label} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.label}} /> : ''}
                {this.props.children}
                {this.props.cta ? <span className={styles.cta}>{this.props.cta}</span> : ''}
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

**Capsule.css**

```
.icon {
    left: 31px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.base {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(114, 110, 101);
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    min-height: 54px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.base + .base { margin-top: 8px; }
.clickable {
    composes: base;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.withIcon {
    composes: base;
    padding-left: 62px;
}
.label {}
.cta {
    color: rgb(216, 213, 210);
}
```

You'll see I'm rendering the `<Icon />` component inside the `<Capsule />` component here, and that I'm passing in a `classes` prop. This is because I need to use the locally-scoped `.icon` class from `Capsule.css` to position the `<Icon />` correctly inside of `<Capsule />`. It's working just fine right now, but I'm not so sure this is ideal, or even the right way to go about it.

Screenshot of results:

[image]

Suggestions for improvement? Really appreciate any help I can get.